# Powershell Modify Select-Object Property Before Output

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, select-object, write-host

How would I go about removing the leading "{Storage consumed:, " and the trailing "}" from the DiskAllocation property of this Select-Object so that only the size remains?

For Example: {Storage consumed:, 48.62 MB} becomes 48.62 MB

I know that I need to do some sort of replace statement with regex, but I am a beginner with Powershell.  Any help would be appreciated.

```
$DS | Select-Object -Property Computer, Name, ObjectType, DiskAllocation | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan
```

The output currently looks like this:

[image: Output]

Comment: The OP probably realized by now, but to anyone coming here from google, this is a classic example of what a lot (including me) of people go through when going to Powershell after a life using members of the Bourne Shell family. The person needs to go through a change in mindset to stop seeing things as text needing to be processed and starting to see things as objects with properties everywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the output, the `DiskAllocation` property holds a two-item array - you can select only the second item with a calculated property:

```
Select-Object -Property Computer, Name, ObjectType, DiskAllocation, @{Name='DiskAllocation';Expression={$_.DiskAllocation[1]}}
```

Comment: You're right, that calculated property is exactly what I needed.  I did need to remove the first "DiskAllocation," you had in your answer.  I was getting Select-Object : The property cannot be processed because the property "DiskAllocation" already exists.  Once I took that out, it worked like a charm.  Thanks for the help!